# What is the relationship between "finite dominant morphism into normal variety is open" and going-down?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

It is standard that "finite morphism is closed" whose proof is essentially going-up. I have found a statement in [this book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-57878-6) stating "finite dominant morphism into normal variety is open" (Part 2 Chap 2 Sec 2.8) whose proof is mysterious. Afterwards the author states that this is equivalent to going-down, but I can't see why. The only indication I know is that some normality is required in going-down.